# Rotate 2D axis around the central x axis

Tags: python, rotation, axis

I have a simple 2D array:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

And would like it to be:

```
array([[ 9,  10,  11,  12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

How could this be done, and then, in general, how could this be done for an [n,m] sort of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.flipud` (up/down) or with similar result `np.flip` on the `axis=0`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
                [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
                [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

flipud_arr = np.flipud(arr)
print(flipud_arr)    

flip_arr = np.flip(arr, axis=0)
print(flip_arr)
```

Both have the same output:

```
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

---

Both work in general, so also for even rows:

```
arr = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
                [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
                [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
                [ 3,  0,  8,  1]])
np.flipud(arr)  # in place = same memory, for copy see 1st code snippet
```

Output:

```
array([[ 3,  0,  8,  1],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Slicing:

```
>>> ar = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
...                [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
...                [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> ar[::-1]
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

This returns an array view, which shares memory with the original array. If you do not want to share memory, copy it:

```
>>> ar[::-1].copy()
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
a = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
         
b = a.copy()

for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i], b[len(a) - i - 1] = a[len(a) - i - 1], a[i]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a method for it in Numpy but one way is to re-index it backwards.
This is how it's done:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

a = a[list(range(len(a)-1,-1,-1))] 
a
```

output:

```
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

[np.flip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) does the job.

```py
>>>A = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>>np.flip(A, axis=0)
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```